# upload a compiled app

Tags: macos, upload, compilation, ftp

when i compile an app i see it as single "executable" on the mac.
if i move it to a Windows computer i see it as a folder containing files.
if i browse it from a forum's attachment button i see it as an `.app.zip` file.

this last file, if downloaded on my mac can be **executed directly without having to unzip it**.

i need to FTP the file to a Server, but if FTP it i get a folder uploaded like when i see it on Windows. right now to upload it i am doing a totally crazy thing: upload to forum, download .app.zip file on Windows, upload to FTP.

how can i upload the file directly from a mac without doing all this crazy stuff, **keeping the "run after download" functionality**?

thanks!

Comment: not quite sure what you're getting at, but I can tell you this: .app is actually a folder on a mac. You can right-click -> show package contents to see what's inside it. Your actual executable will be somewhere in there. The usual way to distribute any program is to put it in a zip or disk image. Seems you want to circumvent that, so have you tried zipping the "package contents" and renaming the result as .app.zip?

Comment: i dont knwo what is happening when i upload an app to a forum. what i would like to do, is to do the exact same thing that happens when i upload to a forum. it could be that the browser automatically zips it.. dont know.. or it just renames it, no clue..

Comment: Well browsers can't upload directories (not yet, although I think there are some hacks), so whichever forum you're using must be zipping it first, which explains the .app.zip. In fact, it's even possible that you could get the same behaviour by just compressing the app file on the mac without messing about in the package contents. Did you actually try that? If it doesn't work you could also try using the `zip` commandline, which avoids some of the sillyness of the built-in behaviour (doesn't add hidden folders, for example)

Comment: the zipping is probably done by the browser itself, not the forums because when i hit the "browse" button to chose the file i already see it as single file, not as a folder. will try and post back! please add your answer as normal answer so i can accpet it, because either way my only solution is to zip it! thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of being able to run a `.app.zip` file directly. You would have to open it twice; the first time to unzip it, then it would be replaced with the original `.app` "file" (actually a directory), then open this file as usual.

I had a play around with zipping `.app` files by various means, and found no way to make the file executable without unzipping first.

In my opinion, the best way to distribute apps is to zip them. Users find unzipping things easy (they just need to double-click them). You can do this in finder (right-click -> compress) or in the terminal with:

```
zip -r MyApp.app.zip MyApp.app
```

To distribute a minimal application which needs no resources, you can right-click the app, go to "Show Package Contents", go "Contents -> MacOS", and copy the executable you find in there. This is the core of your app, and if no resources or other fancy things are used, can be run directly. It's not a good user experience, because it keeps a terminal window open, but if you're desperate to distribute you app as a single, unzipped file, this is the way to go.

You might also be interested in this article: http://daringfireball.net/2009/09/how_should_mac_apps_be_distributed

Comment: hey this execute withoutunzipping feature must be something new to mountain lion, because on the snow leopard mac i have to unzip them! thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Justme interesting. I'm on Lion (not Mountain Lion) and it doesn't do this. Makes sense as a feature. Pity they didn't add it to older versions.